# How to pass the submitted form data along with multipartfile(image) upload and save the data to a javabean on the controller end Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

```
My Html Content
<form role="form" name="frm1" action="http://localhost:8080/aricloud/rest/usermgmt/signup" id="signup" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div class="form-group">`enter code here`
    <label for="username">Login Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username" value="vindu525">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="passwd" placeholder="Password" value="12345">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmpasswd" placeholder="Please enter Password again" value="12345">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailID" id="emailID" placeholder="Enter email" value="vindu525@gmail.com">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="mobile">Mobile No</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobileNumber" id="mobileNumber" placeholder="Enter email" value="9584315174">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country" id="country" placeholder="Enter country" value="india">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="country">File Upload</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="image" >
  </div>

<input type="hidden" class="form-control"  name="userAvatar" id="userAvatar" value="null"/>

  <button id="regsubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

My Controller

```
public ResponseEntity<String> addUser(@RequestBody UserDetailsBean user,
            @Context HttpServletRequest request,
            @Context HttpServletResponse response
            ) {
//File handling and other logic goes here 
}
```

---

UserDetailsBean contains the setter and getter methods for all the form data including the image

---

When I post the data I get the below error
 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Though the individual file and content upload works when I try to integrate the multipartfile with the userdetails bean it gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MultipartHttpServletRequest for this

sample code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNewProduct(MultipartHttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestParam String h) {
        String category = request.getParameter("parmname");
        //other stuff 
}
```